# Where to Store Model Observers (Events) in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Just trying out Laravel events and observers for the first time.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#model-observers

I see in some old postings about Laravel 4 a good place to store them was just in `app/models/observers`. However in Laravel 5 since the folder structure has changed a bit I'm wondering where is a good place to store them?

Should I be storing them in the `Events` folder?

Comment: I define them in the same model class as a sub class because the same observer will not be loaded by different models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of those questions that may have a wrong answer but multiple right answers. I would suggest we re-visit the basics a bit.

I believe the folder structure of a web app should be intuitive. Someone looking at the code for the first time should very quickly understand what to find where. So, here is what I would suggest.

Since Laravel 5 has the models in the `app` folder, you can namespace them to a `Models` folder. Your model code will then be housed at `app/Models`. Similarly, you can keep your model observers at `app/Models/Observers` and namespace them accordingly.

You can also save them in the `Events` folder or a separate `Observers` folder in the `app` folder but as I have said, the above is more intuitive.

Comment: Sub-directories under **app** should be capitalised, as Laravel uses the [PSR-4 auto-loading standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/).

Answer (score 1):

You can store them where ever you want. Laravel doesn’t impose a directory structure for the unique logic of your application.

I *wouldn’t* store them in the **app/Events** directory though, as they are for event classes. A more appropriate location may be something like **app/Observers**, or **app/Model/Observers** if you want to retain some familiarity from Laravel 4.

Answer (score 0):

I define them in the same model class file because the same observer will not be loaded by different models (most of the time).

Although if your observers are being shared by different models then do make a separate folder, in the app folder, and add it to composer autoload and define the observer classes there.